# Функция замены подтстрок вида {{first_name}} переменными

Tags: php, массивы, строки, замена

Есть текст вида:

```
$str = "Приветствую, {{first_name}} {{last_name}}!";
```

В массиве есть переменные `$first, $last`.
Нужно заменить в строке `{{first_name}}->$first, {{last_name}}->$last`

Делал так:

```
$trans = array(
    "{{first_name}}" => $first, 
    "{{last_name}}"  => $last, 
    "{{cart}}"       => $crt1, 
    "{{phone}}"      => $phone, 
    "{{addr}}"       => $addr, 
    "{{order_id}}"   => $order_id
);


function replace_str($str, $trans) {
    $subj = strtr($str, $trans);
    return $subj;
}

$cart = replace_str($str, $trans);
```

Но `strtr` не работает с кириллицей. Подскажите, пожалуйста, аналогичное решение.

Answer (score 0):

использую [mb_strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strstr.php),
поддерживает разные кодировки

или `str_replace()`

```
$str = "Приветствую, {{first_name}} {{last_name}}!";
$from = ["{{first_name}}", "{{last_name}}"];
$to   = [$first, $last];

$newphrase = str_replace($from, $to, $str);
```

Comment: Но mb_strstr() не поддерживает массивы. В итоге конечно придется с ней возиться, но решение с массивом мне кажется удобным.

Comment: @АлексейБондарь `str_replace()` не подходит?